# Can't use Imgur API on localhost: 429 errors

Tags: localhost, imgur, http-status-code-429

I am consistently getting a 429 and this error:

```
Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later.
```

The [Imgur status page](https://status.imgur.com/) indicates "All Systems Operational" and no recent incidents.

Curiously, I don't get this error when I change from using `http://localhost:30000` to `http://127.0.0.1:30000`.

Here's the code I'm using to make the request (copied directly from the [API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/)):

```
const base64 = ""; // A base64 encoded png (7 kb)
const clientID = ""; // My Imgur Client ID

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", `Client-ID ${clientID}`);

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", base64);

const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: formData,
    redirect: "follow",
};

const response = await fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", options);
```

Comment: this only happens if you are on localhost. It happend to me as well. When the app is configured to redirect to a non local address it works. Maybe this is due to the usage http instead of https for localhost